# PHP $_POST function not recognizing HTML form input value

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I can't seem to apply the `$_POST` function properly to retrieve the data from a simple HTML form.  I'm new to PHP, so I may be overlooking something simple.

I have a form with action directing to the same page, but if the form is filled out, the value of `$_POST['input_name']` will have changed, so I can trigger the php function using that condition.  Is this the best way to structure this kind of action?

Here's my HTML code (thispage.php is the current/same page):

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's my PHP code from the same page:

```
if("" == trim($_POST['userName'])){
  echo $_POST['userName'];
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: If the posted value equals an empty string then what exactly do you expect to *see* from that `echo` statement?

Comment: **STYLE ONLY POINT**: username does not have camelCase in it as it is a recognised word in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/username)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove the action from `form` if your server side code is in the same page. And Use the `empty()` or `isset()` functions for checking the value.

For Example:

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['userName']))){
  echo $_POST['userName'];
}

if(isset(trim($_POST['userName']))){
  echo $_POST['userName'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if("" == trim($_POST['userName'])){
  echo $_POST['userName'];
}
```

This is actually checking if the value is empty and echoes it if it is.

You probably want to use `!empty($_POST['userName'])` to check if it's not empty and then echo it if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

HTML code

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP code on the same page:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset(trim($_POST['userName']))){
        echo $_POST['userName'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if(trim($_POST['userName']) != ' '){
    echo $_POST['userName'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try it:

```
if(isset($_POST['userName'])){
 $name = $_POST['userName'];
 echo $name;
}
```